# telebot python, inline кнопка

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, inline

Бот отправляет инлайн кнопку на канал где есть много людей, нужно чтоб для каждого пользователя кнопка была одноразовой, чтоб когда каждый пользователь кликал на него и только у него пропадало кнопка. и еще не предлагайте решение с связанное с базой данных, так приложение будет работать медленнее. я видел у других каналов что есть такое но не знаю как реализовать. вот ниже мой код

```
insertViewInline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
accept = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="accpet", callback_data="acceptView")
insertViewInline.add(accept)
bot.send_message(chat_id, "inlineButton", reply_markup=insertViewInline)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    if(call.data == 'acceptView'):
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, text='You accepted')
        #здесь надо чтоб кнопка пропало, или как то по другому надо
```

Comment: возможно подойдёт изменение сообщения (удаление кнопки, но не текста): `bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text='{}'.format(call.message.text))`

Comment: types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()

Comment: обе варианта не решают проблему, мне надо удалить кнопку только у одного пользователя а не у всех, а types.ReplyKeyboardRemove() не подходит для inline кнопок

Comment: к сожалению, изменять сообщение в общей группе\канале для конкретного участника невозможно

Comment: @Yanun вам удалось реализовать задуманное?

Comment: @Violet к сожалению так как я хотел нет, сделал две кнопки, сначала пользователь кликал на него, а потом таймер был 1-2 минуты, если он кликал по второй кнопке то значит был он, но там не так хорошо работало, может если посмотреть другие библиотеки может там найдете нормальное что то

Comment: у вас сохранились ссылки на каналы? "видел у других каналов что есть такое"

Comment: @Violet к сожалению нет.